# track rewind slider in pygame slows down

Tags: python

I have a slider in ui on pyside2, I need to play tracks on Pygame and I added time rewind, but it lags a lot when using it

```
self.seek_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.seek_slider.setGeometry(10, 90, 200, 30)
        self.seek_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.seek)
```

```
def seek(self, value):
        if self.playlist and self.playing:
            length = pygame.mixer.Sound(self.playlist[self.current_track]).get_length()
            pos = value / 100.0 * length
            pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(pos)
```

smooth rewinding and slider following the track is required